# PostGIS: Filtering multipolygon by Boundary

Tags: postgresql, postgis, intersection, polygons

I have a table with column geom in my PostgreSQL database (version 9.3), containing a multipolygon.  Then I have a line object, that builds a boundary. I'm trying to build a view with all geom objects that are within the boundary object.

I tried the functions ST_Within (can't handle multipolygons) and ST_Intersects...

Here is my SQL command:

```
CREATE VIEW buildings_intersect_boundary AS
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "buildings".gid ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER,
      "buildings".name,"buildings".type,
      "buildings".geom
FROM   "buildings" INNER JOIN "boundary" ON 
      ST_Intersects("buildings".geom,"boundary".geom)
```

At the moment I solve the problem by using bounding boxes:

```
CREATE VIEW osm_buildings_intersect_project_boundary AS
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "buildings_fromOSMShape".gid ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER,
       "buildings_fromOSMShape".name,"buildings_fromOSMShape".type,
       "buildings_fromOSMShape".geom
FROM   "buildings_fromOSMShape" INNER JOIN "boundary_project_area" ON 
       "buildings_fromOSMShape".geom @ "boundary_project_area".geom
```

But this returns too many objects...

Operating system:  Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for ST_Contains, which is like ST_Intersects, but excludes geometries which are not fully contained -- you say you want objects that are within others. ST_Within gives you geometries within a distance of others, not inside them.

```
CREATE VIEW osm_buildings_intersect_project_boundary AS 
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY buildings.gid ASC) AS ROW_NUMBER,
     buildings.name, buildings.type, buildings.geom
  FROM  "buildings_fromOSMShape" buildings, "boundary_project_area" boundaries  
      WHERE ST_Contains(boundaries.geom, buildings.geom)
```

Personally, I prefer writing ST_Contains and ST_Intersects queries in this way, as I think it is clearer than using inner join when the join key is actually a spatial condition, not an equality constraint, though the query will be executed the same. I also aliased your table names for readability/brevity purposes. Note that with ST_Contains the order of the geometries matters, unlike with ST_Intersects, where it does not.

Comment: hey john, thx for your answer. i tried it and data couldn't be displayed. unfortunately i think your query will not help me. the officially doc says, that geometrycollections ar not supported (http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html[link])... any other suggestions?

Comment: Ah, you have geometry collections. Yes they are painful to work with. Do you only have polygons and multipolygons or do you have lines and points too?

Comment: i think there are only polygons, but unfortunatly i can't exclude that there are some other geometries...

Comment: You said before that my approach wouldn't work because GeometryCollections are not supported and now you just said that you only have Polygons. There are ways of dealing with these things, once we are clear on what your data look like. Could you perhaps edit your question to include an example of your geometries and what you expect from the query.

Comment: sorry for answering so late. Unfortunately it's too long ago, so I can't say... I don't have my data around, because my old laptop was broken :-/

Comment: sorry about the laptop. No worries.